# Oracle PL/SQL Query With Dynamic Parameters in Where Clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a dynamic query that could have a different amount of parameters of different type. The only issue I'm having is handling if the value is a string therefore needing single quotes around it. I am using the value of a field called key_ref_ to determine what my where clause will look like. Some examples are:

```
LINE_NO=1^ORDER_NO=P6002277^RECEIPT_NO=1^RELEASE_NO=1^

PART_NO=221091^PART_REV=R02^
```

At the moment I am replacing the '^' with ' and ' like this:

```
REPLACE( key_ref_, '^' ,' and ' );
```

Then I'm trying to create the dynamic query like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'select '||column_name_||' into column_ from '||base_table_||' where '||
 key_ref_ || 'rownum = 1';
```

This won't work in cases where the value is not a number.

Also I only added "rownum = 1" to handle the extra 'and' at the end instead of removing the last occurence.

Comment: Not very clear what exactly your issue is. Can you please post some examples.

Comment: You should not do this that way. As there are plenty possibilities for sql injection and you have to write a parser for your conditions. Better use a user defined datatype to define the conditions and then use `DBMS_SQL` instead of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and bind the parameters to your query...

Comment: I won't need to worry about sql injection as there is no user input, it's just part of a background job but I will look into using DBMS_SQL instead

Comment: Ok then it isn't that bad, but binding the parameters is allways useful, as string literals in the query lead to different entries in the database cache. Which will influence overall system performance counterproductive...

Comment: @Radagast81 why do you think DBMS_SQL would be better than EXECUTE IMMEDIATE? NB, in newer Oracle releases (i.e. >=12.1) you can also use user defined datatypes in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input will not have the tild symbol(~) then you can try the below code.
if the input has tild, you can replace it with some other value which should not be there in input

considering the input provided in the example..

```
LINE_NO=1^ORDER_NO=P6002277^RECEIPT_NO=1^RELEASE_NO=1^PART_NO=221091^PART_REV=R02^
```

use the below code

```
replace(replace(replace('LINE_NO=1^ORDER_NO=P6002277^RECEIPT_NO=1^RELEASE_NO=1^PART_NO=221091^PART_REV=R02^','^','~ and '),'=','=~'),'~',q'[']')
```

and the result would be

```
LINE_NO='1' and ORDER_NO='P6002277' and RECEIPT_NO='1' and RELEASE_NO='1' and PART_NO='221091' and PART_REV='R02' and
```

System will type cast the number fields so, there would not be any issue.

Comment: Thank you that worked. What is the purpose of the '~' ?

Comment: I think `~` is just a random character which intends to not occur in your dynamic string.